# Django referencing a ManyToManyField within the same model error without quotations

Tags: python, django, syntax, manytomanyfield

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

So I based my code off this document and I hit an error.

```
from django.db import models

class Gift(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
      max_length=120, unique=True, help_text='Enter the gift item name'
    )
    # skipping to the ManyToMany ....
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

class Category(models.Model):
    # skipping stuff like CATEGORIES ...
    type = models.IntegerField(
      primary_key   = True, choices = CATEGORIES, default = EVENT,
    )
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
```

I receive this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/.../gifting_db/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/.../gifting_db/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/.../gifting_db/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/.../gifting_db/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/.../gifting_db/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/.../gifting_db/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/.../gifting_db/gifting/gifts/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Gift(models.Model):
  File "/.../gifting_db/gifting/gifts/models.py", line 20, in Gift
    category    = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
NameError: name 'Category' is not defined
```

But if I add quotations to the 'Category' it works. Any idea why? The django doc example does not use quotations https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ between the 'Publication' and 'Article'. If anything, I would guess I'm putting 'Category' in as a string, not as a reference to the Category object?

```
genre = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `Category` is not defined until after `Gift`. If you want to use it without quotes you need to place `Category` above `Gift`. Otherwise, quotations work fine and provide the same functionality.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been
>   defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model
>   object itself:

Comment: Ah that's why it worked with the quotes. Awesome thank you, I missed that in the foreign key section.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `Category` before `Gift` or use quotes.

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    # skipping stuff like CATEGORIES ...
    type = models.IntegerField(
    primary_key = True, choices=CATEGORIES, default=EVENT)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)


class Gift(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True, help_text='Enter the gift item name'
    )
    # skipping to the ManyToMany ....
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

Or `use quotes`

```
from django.db import models


class Gift(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True, help_text='Enter the gift item name'
    )
    # skipping to the ManyToMany ....
    genre = models.ManyToManyField('Category')


class Category(models.Model):
    # skipping stuff like CATEGORIES ...
    type = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, choices=CATEGORIES, default=EVENT,)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True
```